# Django -Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Method

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am very new to Django ,I am trying to run a URL ,however I get this error of page not found.I went through almost 90% of the posts here but nothing worked for me.
Here are three .py files

**views.py.....**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
   return HttpResponse('Hello world....')
```

**products\urls.py****

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views    #.means current folder ,we are importing a module


urlpatterns=[
    path(' ', views.index),
]
```

**pyshop\urls.py.......**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/',include('products.urls'))
]
```

**Error I get.....**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/
Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
products/
The current path, products/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Hi fari my first guess would be to remove the space in path(' ', views.index) e.g. path('', views.index),

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to delete the space on the path :

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path(' ', views.index),
]
```

Like :

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index),
]
```

Comment: Thank You soooo much for the help:) Its working now